# Cypher queries using Neo4j value with special characters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've a neo4j node with a property, `readid`, with the value `HWI-ST884:57:1:1101:13989:75421#0`

When I do a query in the shell, it seems as though I have to escape the `:`, `-` and `#` character. in order to get to the node I want.

```
start n=node:readID('readid:HWI\\-ST884\\:57\\:1\\:1101\\:13989\\:75421\\#0') return n;
```

Is there a way to not have to escape these characters?

The backtick seems to work for the property field but not values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search term is passed to Lucene, so Lucene query syntax applies here. You might try:

```
start n=node:readID('readid:"HWI-ST884:57:1:1101:13989:75421#0"') return n;
```

Comment: Sorry for my noobness, but why is there a need to double escape ie. `//` instead of `/` when escaping these special characters.
    

_Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

    + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

`\(1\+1\)\:2`_